# Android SAF openOutPutStream with append parameter

Tags: android, file, storage-access-framework

With the classic FileSystem API, we can get an output stream with an append parameter to write to the end of a file.

Here is the code I use to acces to the files :

Classic File System API :

```
boolean append = true;
File target = new File(...);
OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(target, append);
```

SAF API :

```
boolean append = true;
File target = new File(...);
DocumentFile targetDocument = getDocumentFile(target, false, context);
OutputStream outStream = context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(targetDocument.getUri());
```

But I don't have the append parameter in the SAF API.

How can we append to a file using the SAF API?

Answer (score 1):

Use this [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openAssetFileDescriptor(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String)). Take a look at the documentation for `mode`, you can pass `"wa"` as the mode to append to an arbitrary file.

However `"wa"` is a complex mode and as indicated in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#openFile(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String)) it needs the file to be seekable, but ParcelFileDescriptor is only seekable when it's obtained from a File object, so not until Android O only providers backed by local storage can support it.

The reason both `openFile()` and `openAssetFile()` are referenced is in the source code of DocumentsProvider is they both delegate to `openDocument()` so both documents are applicable.